# How to parse an error received from a backend and dispatched as an Error object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object, response

> Finally the problem was with the Error object constructor that makes useless the response object that is passed to it in the catch error handler.

I'm using a sdk that has this method: [link to sdk code](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-sdk-javascript/blob/master/src/lib/sdk.ts)

```sh
    /**
     * Axios request
     * @param method Request method
     * @param url Server URL
     * @param requestConfig Custom Axios config
     */
    async request(method, url, requestConfig) {
        try {
            const response = await this.axios.request(Object.assign({ method,
                url }, requestConfig));
            return response.data;
        }
        catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                throw new Error(error.response.data.message);
            }
            else {
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to parse the errors emitted by this method.
I have no problem with the second case - `throw error;`
But I can't parse the message in the first case - `throw new Error(error.response.data.message);`

If I debug the error with `console.log("Error: ", error);` I get `Error:  Error: [object Object]` in the console.

If I debug `console.log('sdk => error.response.data.message: ', error.response.data.message);` in the code above before issuing the error it shows this:

```
sdk => error.response.data.message:  
[{…}]
0:
messages: Array(1)
0: {id: "Auth.form.error.user.not-exist", message: "This email does not exist."}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Maybe the problem is that Error expects a string in its constructor and, therefore, it executes toString() method on the object.

This is the response I get when I look at the NETWORK tab in the Inspecting Tool:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":[{"messages":[{"id":"Auth.form.error.user.not-exist","message":"This email does not exist."}]}]}
```

And I can only output this: `error.message[0]`
If I try `error.message[0].messages` I get undefined.

If I try: `const errorToJSON = JSON.parse(error)` I get this error:

```
Unhandle Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0
```

What I need is the text value of message: "This email does not exist."

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so `error.message[0]. messages[0].message`

Comment: Just an explanation of why it's happening @epascarello is right with their answer. When you call `console.log` it tries to turn everything into a string and (as far as I'm aware) the default `.toString` of an object is `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thank you @epascarello, I get undefined. I'm going to update the question with this detail.

Comment: Why don't you just debug and drill down as you go? Output `error`, check that it has a message property, then output `error.message`, check that it is an array, then output `error.message[0]`, check that it has a messages property, ...etc, ...etc. You can really get this working yourself if you try.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an object to mimic the response. It's important to understand the structure of the object you're inspecting in order to understand how to pull data from it.

`error` is the object being caught in the try/catch

`error.response` is an object holding response data

`error.response.data` is the JSON you see as the return data

`error.response.data.message` is an array of messages

In the following code, you are throwing a new `Error` object and passing the messages array into the constructor. The reason this is failing is because the Error object's constructor requires a `String` type variable.

One option to fix the issue would be to use `JSON.stringify` on the messages array and pass that into the Error object constructor. It's been mentioned that you can also just throw the `error.response.data.message` object as well. It's up to you to figure out if either of these or another option works best for your project.

Here is an example of using the `stringify` method:

```
if (error.response) {
  throw new Error(JSON.stringify(error.response.data.message));
}
```

Here is an example of throwing the messages array:

```
if (error.response) {
  throw error.response.data.message;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @daddygames but if I try to parse the error using JSON.parse(error) I get this error : Unhandled Rejection ( SyntaxError): Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

Comment: If the data is already an object, then calling `JSON.parse(error)` could produce the error you describe. Skip over the parsing part and see if the rest of the answer resolves the issue?

Comment: I get this error - `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. `typeof error.message[0] => string`

Comment: @MiguelÁngelTorres something isn't right on your end that we can't see. Would you mind adding some of the code you are using to the question you posted above? It will be difficult to assist without more information.

Comment: Thank you @daddygame. Yes you're right. I've just updated my question.

Comment: @MiguelÁngelTorres please review the updated answer. regards

Comment: I can't loop on `error.message[0].messages`, it gives me `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(error.message[0]));` gives me `"["`. It seems as if `new Error(error.response.data.message)` had something to do with this strange behavior.

Comment: @MiguelÁngelTorres could you point us to the API for the Error object you are throwing or if this is an object you created, could you provide the code for it?

Comment: I've just updated my question with the link to this sdk. It's deprecated but I still have to use it. Well, the API is generated by Strapi. I suppose It has to be a bit complicated to dig into it. Thanks.

Comment: @MiguelÁngelTorres I'm not familiar with AXIOS, but from what I can tell the Error object wants a String value to be passed to its constructor. So when you call `throw new Error(error.response.data.message)` it doesn't work right because you provided an array... I assume. You may need to extract the messages or stringify the messages array when passing to the new Error object like this: `throw new Error(JSON.stringify(error.response.data.message))` Please give this a try?

Comment: Yes @daddygames. It worked, and obviously it also work if I put `throw error.response.data.message`, so the problem is that, the Error constructor is useless if an object is passed to it. Sorry about this, I guess it's only a problem with a deprecated library. Thank you anyway for your patience.

Comment: @MiguelÁngelTorres I'm glad this helped. I've updated my answer to try to match the resolution we've landed on. If you believe it sufficiently answers your question, I would appreciate a vote on my answer. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you @daddygames, as soon as I'm allowed to vote I'll come back to vote your answer. Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

If the response is returned as a string, you can use the `JSON.parse()` Javascript function to convert it to a JSON object.

Once the response is in JSON format, you can simply retrieve the value by traversing through the response:

```js
var errorMessage = response.message[0].messages[0].message;
```

Comment: Thank you @mitchcout but the response is an object. Well I console.log( typeof error ); and it output object.

Comment: If it is already an object, just skip that step and you should be able to access the value using the above code snippet

Answer (score 0):

[As epascarello says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593194/how-to-parse-an-object-received-from-the-backend-in-javascript#comment103499368_58593194), you should be able to get your error message out with `error.message[0].messages[0].message`. See demo:

```js
const error = {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":[{"messages":[{"id":"Auth.form.error.user.not-exist","message":"This email does not exist."}]}]}

console.log(error.message[0].messages[0].message)
```

Here's why this works.

```
error      // The parent object your message is stored in
.message   // Get the `message` parameter from the object
[0]        // `message` is an array. Get the first object from the array
.messages  // Get the `messages` parameter from the object
[0]        // `message` is also an array. Get the first object from the array
.message   // Get the `message` parameter from the object

{                                                 <------ error
  "statusCode":400,
  "error":"Bad Request",
  "message":[                                     <------ .message
    {                                             <------ [0]
      "messages":[                                <------ .messages
        {                                         <------ [0]
          "id":"Auth.form.error.user.not-exist",
          "message":"This email does not exist."  <------ .message
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if the `message` and `messages` Arrays have something in them. If you're unsure, you can use something like `error.message.flatMap(msg => msg.messages.map(innerMsg => innerMsg.message))`

Comment: Thank you James. If I put `error.message[0].messages[0]` I get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and if I try `error.message.flatMap(msg => msg.messages.map(innerMsg => innerMsg.message))` I get `TypeError: error.message.flatMap is not a function`

Comment: It sounds like `message` isn't an Array in your case... `flatMap` and `map` are Array functions.

Comment: or your error object doesn't contain a `message` at all (since it's complaining about `undefined`).

Comment: Maybe new Error(error.response.data.message) had something to do with this.